# How to do java unit test with protobuf for controller?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test-mvc, protobuf-java

I have a spring boot rest controller with requestBody & responseBody both protobuf. like below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/position/open", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
@ResponseBody
public MsgProto.Response positionOpen(@RequestBody MsgProto.Request request)throws Exception {
    log.info("start /position/open");
    return orderPositionService.addOrder(request);
}
```

Now I want to do a unit test using **mockMvc** to test the controller, but it failed every time. I believe it is the code below which is wrong to fire an HTTP request with **protobuf**, any idea how to resolve it?

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/position/open").contentType("application/x-protobuf")
            .content(ObjectsMock.mockMsgProtoRequest().toByteArray())).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Exception :

```
Resolved Exception:
         Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException
MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 415
Error message = null
      Headers = [Accept:"application/json, application/octet-stream, 
application/xml, application/*+json, text/plain, text/xml, application/x-www- 
form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, multipart/mixed, */*"]
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace for this failed test scenario?

Comment: @rieckpil  I posted here. not sure how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` is missing here. Spring MVC can't read/write any messages without this specific converter.

You can create it as the following:

```
@Bean
public ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
  return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

Next, make sure to add the HTTP Method to your method, as I assume (from reading your test) you want this to be a HTTP POST handler. You can also add the `consumes` attribute to state that this endpoint also consumes Protobuf.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-protobuf", value = "/position/open", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
@ResponseBody
public MsgProto.Response positionOpen(@RequestBody MsgProto.Request request)throws Exception {
    log.info("start /position/open");
    return orderPositionService.addOrder(request);
}
```

In addition to this, there is an [article on the Spring blog available](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services) that covers your usecase and explains how to use Protobuf with Spring MVC.

Comment: This can't solve the problem. As there is no issue to fire a normal request but there is an issue firing the Mockmvc test when in JUnit where the above exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Protobuf converter to MockMvc builder

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
               .setMessageConverters(new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter())
               .build()
```

This fixed the issue for me